# Upload image without src attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, canvas

We gave an option for user to Upload the image

Image is uploading fine, but its not adding any **img src tag** for that uploaded image.... Is this is acceptable to upload image without using any img tag ? will it lead to any problems in future ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
// dont have a webserver so im using base64string instead
   
var maskedImageUrla = "data:image/png;base64,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";
                
    // maskedImage one
    var mask1 = $(".container").mask({
        maskImageUrl: maskedImageUrla,
        onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
            // add your style to the img example below
            img.css({
                "left": 105,
                "top": 5
            })
        }
    });
    
    fileupa1.onchange = function() {
        mask1.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileupa1.files[0]));
    };

    

}); // end of document ready

// jq plugin for mask
(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString() + JQmasks.length,
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onImageCreate: function(img) {},
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {}
        }, options);


        var container = {};


        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div,
            obj = $(this);

        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        };

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset();
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0;
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id === id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
            prevX = pos.x;
            prevY = pos.y;
            return $(item);
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        };

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        };


        container.getImagePosition = function() {
            return {
                x: settings.x,
                y: settings.y,
                scale: settings.scale
            };
        };

        container.onDragOver = function(evt) {
            if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
                var pos = container.mousePosition(evt);
                var x = settings.x + pos.x - prevX;
                var y = settings.y + pos.y - prevY;
                if (x === settings.x && y === settings.y)
                    return; // position has not changed
                settings.x = x;
                settings.y = y;
                prevX = pos.x;
                prevY = pos.y;
                container.updateStyle();
            }
        };

        container.updateStyle = function() {

            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";

            if (initImage || !image) {
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    if (settings.onImageCreate)
                        settings.onImageCreate(image);

                    canvas.width = image.width * settings.scale;
                    canvas.height = image.height * settings.scale;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                };
            } else {
                context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
            }

            if (initImage || !img) {
                img = new Image();
                img.src = settings.imageUrl || "";
                img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                img.onload = function() {
                    settings.x = settings.x === 0 && initImage === true ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                    settings.y = settings.y === 0 && initImage === true ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                    context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                    initImage = false;
                };
            } else {
                context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
            }
        };

        // change the draggable image
        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            if (img)
                img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;

            container.updateStyle();
        };

        container.createCanvas = function() {
            if (canvas)
                canvas.remove();
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            div.append(canvas);
            div.find("canvas").hover(container.selected);
            div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', container.selected);
            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === true) return;
                event.handled = true;
                JQmasks.forEach(function(item) {
                    item.item.disable();
                });
            });
            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
        };


        // change the masked Image
        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            if (div)
                div.remove();


            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            });
            container.createCanvas();
            obj.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        });

        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    display: flex;
    background: red;
}

.container canvas {
    display: block;
}

.masked-img {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

image 1 
<input id="fileupa1"  type="file" >

<div class="container">
</div>
```

Here is [Codepen](https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/LvXqNb) & [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mf5p6rh3/)

Please let me know if you need more information....

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to:

1) Avoid `(function($) {})`

2) Use several **non-abstract** objects to handle your logic. **Abstract** objects are much harder to read and understand, I find them harder to refactor and to use inheritance.

You can write `vanilla Javascript`, `CoffeeScript` or ES6 using `classes`.

> ## [Class-based vs prototype-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Class-based_vs_prototype-based)
>
> In **class-based** languages the classes are defined beforehand and the objects are instantiated based on the classes. If two objects apple and orange are instantiated from the class Fruit, they are inherently fruits and it is guaranteed that you may handle them in the same way; e.g. a programmer can expect the existence of the same attributes such as color or sugar content or is ripe.
>
> In **prototype-based** languages the objects are the primary entities. No classes even exist. The prototype of an object is just another object to which the object is linked. Every object has one prototype link (and only one). New objects can be created based on already existing objects chosen as their prototype. You may call two different objects apple and orange a fruit, if the object fruit exists, and both apple and orange have fruit as their prototype. The idea of the fruit class doesn't exist explicitly, but as the equivalence class of the objects sharing the same prototype. The attributes and methods of the prototype are delegated to all the objects of the equivalence class defined by this prototype. The attributes and methods owned individually by the object may not be shared by other objects of the same equivalence class; e.g. the attributes sugar content may be unexpectedly not present in apple. Only single inheritance can be implemented through the prototype.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot for reply in weekend, but what to do with img tag ? Is that required? Can we zoom the uploaded image without using img tag ?

Comment: @vickeycolors sorry but discussions about troubleshooting should be done on `Stackoverflow`. Your question on stackoverflow is too complex to be answered. You need to break down your problem into steps and figure out which is the code breaking your functionality and build a [**minimal**, complete, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your example is not **minimal** on stackoverflow and many users will prioritize other questions.

Comment: @vickeycolors My point is, if you would be following the `Class-based` pattern instead of the `prototype-based` pattern, write high-quality code, maybe with unit tests, you could have code like [in this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/219232/ruby-version-rotate-linked-list-to-the-right-by-k-places#comment423464_219232) which is easier to read and mantain. You can easily take the `def rotate` method from those classes and get your answer on StackOverflow. Unluckily `95%` of questions on SO are not about issues but code quality